# Best way to convert FCPATH to base_url()

Tags: php, codeigniter, path

What is the best way to convert the path of a file in FCPATH format into the base_url() format?

Comment: What is the purpose of that ?

Comment: I need to put into the db the base url and i have in input the FCPATH of the file

Comment: $url = "/var/www/site1/public/file/abc.jpg";
$url = base_url() . str_replace(FCPATH,"",$url);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$source_path = "/var/www/ci/htdocs/assets/images/";
echo str_replace(FCPATH, base_url(), $source_path);
```

outputs: `http://example.com/assets/images/`

Seems to me it would be much easier to just

```
echo base_url('assets/images/');
```

Comment: The problem is that i don't know the string that you passed in base_url, but i have it saved as FCPATH in the db. Thanks for the answer